# Rails 4 form for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 types of references `fea_ref`, `se_ref`, `te_ref`.

I wanted to make a rails form_for called `_referenceform.html.erb` that takes a parameter (either `@fea_ref, @se_ref, @te_ref`) and create a new one via the the form.

**fea_refs/_new.html.erb**

```
<% render 'referenceform', :object => @fea_ref %>
```

**application/_referenceform.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @object, remote: true, do |f| %> 
  ... 
<% end %>
```

When I hit save and close the modal to create the new fea_ref, I get an error saying,

> param can't be empty or nil, @fea_ref

What could I be missing? Any guidance would be appreciated.

**EDITED**: I also tried

```
<% render 'referenceform', :object => FEARef.new %>
```

to no avail.

Comment: First of all,  `<% render 'referenceform', :object => @fea_ref %>` should be  `<%= render 'referenceform', :object => @fea_ref %>`, you missed `=`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing form object as locals,

If you want to use the partial in the path, `application/_referenceform.html.erb`

```
<%= render :partial => "application/referenceform", :locals=>{:object=>@fea_ref } %>
```

else, if in the same path,

```
<%= render :partial => "referenceform", :locals=>{:object=>@fea_ref } %>
```

Then in the form, you can use,

```
<%= form_for object, remote: true, do |f| %>

    #### your code goes here ####

<% end %>
```